# Basic jQuery accordion with slideUp and slideDown, bottom margin inconsistent, moves about 1 px on panel change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am building a very simple accordion and I can't seem to get pass the following:

The bottom margin of the accordion moves about 1 px when you switch between panels.

In order to observe this, you'll have to change panels consecutively.

**Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r3vathbo/29/).**

HTML:

```
  <div id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-one">
            <div class="title">title one</div>
            <div class="content">content one</div>
        </div>
         <div class="panel panel-two">
            <div class="title">title two</div>
            <div class="content">content two</div>
        </div> 
         <div class="panel panel-three">
            <div class="title">title three</div>
            <div class="content">content three</div>
        </div>
         <div class="panel panel-four">
            <div class="title">title four</div>
            <div class="content">content four</div>
        </div> 
     <div>
```

JS

```
$('.title').on('click', function(e) {

    $('.content').slideUp('active');

    var target = $(this).next('.content');

    if (target.is(':visible')) {
        target.slideUp();
    } else {
        target.slideDown();
    }
});
```

CSS

```
#accordion {
    width: 400px;
}

.title {
    background: blue;
    padding: 10px;
    position: realtive;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

.content {
    background: red;
    padding: 25px;
    display: none;
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this isuse?

Comment: Chrome39 shows no flickering.

Comment: Also can not reproduce. Tested in all latest browsers. Can you include the specific browser and version you are experiencing this in?

Comment: Please look at the bottom margin of the accordion, it moves up and down about one pixel when you change panels in consecutive order

Comment: On a side note, explore slideToggle();

Comment: You are right, but I have read all over the net, and can't find a solution for this very simple thing... the only accordion I've seen not behaving like this is the jQuery UI accordion - but I do not want to use the library for an accordion.... any ideas on why this behaves like this?